# On setting up a gitlab-runner within docker in a self-hosted gitlab setup

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gitlab

I have a self-hosted gitlab instance in Ubuntu. I want to serve a simple static site for my colleagues in the lab, only accessible for those having an account in the server.

According to what I understand:

- To serve a simlpe html file, I need to use "CI/CD".
- "CI/CD" is a mechanism that takes your fresh push and compile, test, parse, or do whatever it needs in order for get ready for release.
- To get CI/CD configured, I need to setup a "gitlab-runner", which, for security purposes should be a completely different machine. Or, I could [use docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) in the same machine at the expense of resources (this is what I want to achieve).

There are many tutorials around, but I am so confused, because I am not familiar with docker or its terminology ([I am getting there](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)), I know just enough gitlab to get it to run, and have no idea what a DNS A record is. Also, I keep staying for a while in a tutorial/website to realize I am in the wrong spot. You could have gitlab within docker, [dockers within](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) the gitlab-runner, gitlab-runner within docker...

I would like to ask for some high level view or guidance on what is the roadmap to get this thing done. Is my understanding so far correct? The guide in [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) results confusing to me because I don't fully get where config/commands should be stored/run (in the host/docker/repo?). I would like to put "my research" here, but at this point, I am not sure on what is relevant:

- [Installation on Linux](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html) (I think I will need to issue all of this inside the docker)
- [Connecting from within docker to the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) (I will need this later)
- [SO. Cannot connect runner to gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092498/gitlab-ci-with-gitlab-setup-self-hosted) (No mention of docker)
- [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) (This seems to be gitlab-runner launching the dockers, so no my case)

Thanks.

### Some extra details:

- I already have a publicly accessible url (that I requested to the IT people)
- Also, already enabled GitLab Pages on `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'https://my.external.url'
# ...
pages_external_url 'http://my.external.url'
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
```

- I have 5 ports forwarding to my router: 80, 443, and three more.
- I already got docker installed on the server. It reports a new network interface: `docker0: 172.17.0.1`.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the authorization part of the question: Setting up a CI pipeline won’t help with that at all. GitLab supports acting as an OAuth and OpenID Connect provider. But all that complexity for a simple website? I don’t know. Setting up GitLab Pages is even more complicated and I must recommend against it.

Comment: A couple of things: (1) I thought I was precisely setting up Gitlab Pages, I already enabled it on the gitlab.rb, installed docker in the server, and to my understanding, the only thing needed was a gitlab-runner to deploy the code upon push. (2) Why setting up the CI pipeline wouldn't help? (3) If you wouldn't advice setting up GitLab pages, then what could I use? (4) I just added some extra info about what I have done.

Comment: @DanielB I get that GitLab pages could be a bit overkill, but I think I shouldn't be that far from getting it to work. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hm. I don’t really want to drag this out using comments. Maybe head over to chat, you have enough reputation to create chat rooms. There are too many unknows in my opinion. // I’d just use some basic webserver with HTTP Basic auth. Not GitLab.